# How do we get more options when flagging a question as belonging on another SE site?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flagging

At the moment, at least for me, the only option I see for recommending migration of a question is to BSE meta. In my opinion, there needs to be either a wider set of choices available to which to recommend migration, or a "fill in the blank" option where the flagger can make a specific recommendation, or some combination of the two.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261196/238438. So far I haven't really noticed a lot of content consistently showing up which definitely belongs on another site, so I'm not sure we need any default paths (yet). For now, if you see something, flag it as "other" and one of the mods can migrate it.

Comment: related, essentially same question: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/824/off-topic-other-stack-exchange-network-limited-options-why